# Passwordless sudo login into a server using Ansible

Tags: ansible, sudoers

I have an Ansible script using which I would like to run some installation related commands on the remote server. But for installation to go through it is required to be a root user or sudo. I am trying to add the user to the sudoers but it is not working.

```
---
- hosts: webservers
  gather_facts: no
  become: yes
  tasks:
        - name: Make sure we have a 'wheel' group
          group:
            name: wheel
            state: present

        - name: Allow 'wheel' group to have passwordless sudo
          lineinfile:
            dest: /etc/sudoers
            state: present
            regexp: '^%wheel'
            line: '%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL'

        - name: Add sudoers users to abkari group
          user: name=abkari groups=wheel append=yes state=present createhome=no
```

On CentOS `wheel` group is the default group for sudo access. When I run this command it doesn't allow to execute the 1st task. What is the problem here?

Comment: Please post the exact error message. Also, what user are you running this play as? If as `abkari`, then you can't perform these actions without having sudo permissions beforehand.

Comment: I am running this as abkari. Yes it would not work. So does it mean i have to use root only to enable passwordless sudo?

Comment: That's how permissions work in Unix-derived systems. You can't obtain root permissions without root granting them.

Comment: The playbook requires pre-existing admin privileges.  A good practice is to have a local admin account with sudo and to disable root login, via both terminal and SSH.  You'll add the local admin at build time, and then use it to add the network group containing your administrators' accounts.  A good way to do that is through `/etc/sudoers.d/<filename>`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for a non-privileged user to grant itself root privileges (either by editing the `sudoers` file or adding itself to the `wheel` group) on a properly configured system.

You need either to run the attached playbook explicitly as root, or configure the system using the root account before you can use `become` in Ansible.

Answer (score -1):

You can add "become: yes", under the "name" of your task (at the same level). 
It allows to perform the task as sudo.

Comment: Which, besides being a copy of [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44375785/2947502), won't change anything, because all the tasks inherit `become: yes` defined at the play level.

Comment: `become: true` requires pre-existing elevated permissions.